# How to get notified when a stripe invoice status is updated or changed?

Tags: triggers, stripe-payments, stripe-apps

The problem I face here is whenever a customer's invoice status is changing from '**draft**' or '**pending**' to '**paid**' I am not getting notified , so have to check manually each time whether the status is changed or not.

It would be very helpful if there is any way of getting notified through mail or any other medium whenever a status is changed

Thank You

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Stripe provides a [Webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) mechanism that notifies your application when an event happens in your account. In order to monitor the Invoice updates, you can listen to this event [`invoice.updated`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.updated). Otherwise, here is some other events related to Invoice activity:

- [invoice.created](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.created)
- [invoice.deleted](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.deleted)
- [invoice.paid](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.paid)
- [invoice.finalized](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.finalized)
- [invoice.finalization_failed](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.finalization_failed)
- [invoice.marked_uncollectible](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.marked_uncollectible)